# Maximum amount of items in one Page of Yii

Tags: php, yii

I am developing this yii application and in the index i am displaying a "preview" of these items and currently it is display 8 items then it will pageinate itself. I would like make it page every 4 items and i have searched online and found that i could use the CPagination. I have followed the example in the documentation http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CPagination and it is working but i don't know how to display the model i have the following code in the index.

```
foreach($models as $model):
endforeach;
$this->widget('CLinkPager', array(
    'pages' => $pages,
));
```

Also the data that i want to display is Title, Content, Image and id and can i use the **_view** since i have everying set from there regarding css.

Also by defult the yii application display the index with a CListView is there a way where i can set the item limit there instead of using CPagination

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just display 4 items on the index page, edit the index action like this:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('{Model}',
    array(
        'criteria' => array(
            'select' => 'title_field,content_field,image_field',
            'limit' => {Limit},
        )
    ));
    $this->render('index',array(
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    ));
}
```

This code will return {Limit} models from the database, if you want to sort them by any field you will need to add 'order' to the criteria array lik this:

```
        'criteria' => array(
            'select' => 'title_field,content_field,image_field',
            'order' => 'download_id DESC',
            'limit' => {Limit},
        )
```

In your view, use foreach and render partial to render the _view.

```
 foreach($models as $model):
     $this->renderPartial('//{Model}/_view', $model);
 endforeach;
```

Hope that helps.